# Meaning of the notification Firefox seems slow to start?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-quantum

Hi Firefox experts,

When launching Firefox, it sometimes displays at the bottom a

- notification saying "Mozilla Firefox seems slow... to... start."
- Is this an official notification type within Firefox? Because I never saw this notification before with older versions (pre v70.0).

What may be a cause for this notification to appear irregurarly? I have not any addons. Could I do something to my profile folder?

Other than that Firefox is working just perfect, have not any issues and not any observable differences to older versions. Thank you

Comment: What's actually in those dots? What OS are you using?

Comment: It has been around since before Firefox 28: [I have a message at the bottom of the window saying Firefox seems slow to start with some buttons to push. this reminds me of PHishing, is it? if so, how rid?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/995438).

Comment: If it happens only sometimes, check if the system is not being slow at _everything_ at that moment. Although Firefox complains about a slow start, the problem might be other application or a temporary condition.

Answer (score 2):

#### Mozilla Firefox seems slow... to... start.

> I never saw this notification before with older versions (pre v70.0).

That message has been in Firefox since 2014 (if not longer).

> That is a valid message that shows if Firefox starts slow.
>
> Some solutions are in the [Firefox takes a long time to start up article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-takes-long-time-start-up)

Source [I have a message at the bottom of the window saying Firefox seems slow to start with some buttons to push. this reminds me of PHishing, is it? if so, how rid? | Firefox Support Forum | Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/995438)